# Mulesoft NetSuite Connector throw java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName Error

Tags: mule, netsuite, mulesoft, mule-component, mule-connector

I am getting this error in my mulesoft application while making a search call to NetSuite connector (v11.5.12).

```
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://client.internal.soap.mule.org/}ProxyService#{http://client.internal.soap.mule.org/}invoke has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName
```

This error has suddenly started to come in the production environment. I am not able to replicate the same in lower environment.

Mule Application is deployment on Anypoint CloudHub with Mule Runtime version 4.4.0
NetSuite connector version v11.5.12
No recent changes deployed to production, existing application started to throw this error while searching

I enabled NetSuite Debug Logger and below are the logs it generated.

```
        DEBUG 2023-02-15 13:50:53,636 [[finance-bulk-api].NetSuite_Config.04 SelectorRunner] [processor: netsuite-advance-search/processors/1/processors/0/processors/0; event: a91c2ba0-ad09-11ed-b6b5-88665a243a09] org.mule.service.http.impl.service.HttpMessageLogger.NetSuite_Config: REQUESTER
    POST /services/NetSuitePort_2021_1 HTTP/1.1
    SOAPAction: search
    Host: 1111.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com
    User-Agent: AHC/1.0
    Connection: keep-alive
    Accept: */*
    Content-Type: text/xml
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    
    c57
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Header><preferences xmlns="urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"><warningAsError>false</warningAsError><disableMandatoryCustomFieldValidation>false</disableMandatoryCustomFieldValidation><disableSystemNotesForCustomFields>false</disableSystemNotesForCustomFields><ignoreReadOnlyFields>false</ignoreReadOnlyFields><runServerSuiteScriptAndTriggerWorkflows>false</runServerSuiteScriptAndTriggerWorkflows></preferences><tokenPassport xmlns="urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"><account xmlns="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">****</account><consumerKey xmlns="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">*****</consumerKey><token xmlns="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">****</token><nonce xmlns="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">****</nonce><timestamp xmlns="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">****</timestamp><signature xmlns="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" algorithm="HMAC_SHA256">fhpl/bxKP/cfuAYhSQ/MULWdkfjfnkfkUlMbWguVr9a6MaXS5fhRUDJVIdjdonddU=</signature></tokenPassport><searchPreferences xmlns="urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"><bodyFieldsOnly>false</bodyFieldsOnly><returnSearchColumns>true</returnSearchColumns><pageSize>10</pageSize></searchPreferences></soap:Header><soap:Body><ns0:search xmlns:ns0="urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
      <ns0:searchRecord xmlns:ns01="urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns01:TransactionSearchAdvanced">
        <ns01:criteria xmlns:ns01="urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
          <ns01:basic>
            <ns02:lastModifiedDate xmlns:ns02="urn:common_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" operator="within">
              <ns03:searchValue xmlns:ns03="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">2023-02-13T22:00:49</ns03:searchValue>
              <ns03:searchValue2 xmlns:ns03="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">2023-02-14T22:00:49</ns03:searchValue2>
            </ns02:lastModifiedDate>
            <ns02:recordType xmlns:ns02="urn:common_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" operator="is">
              <ns03:searchValue xmlns:ns03="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">Invoice</ns03:searchValue>
            </ns02:recordType>
          </ns01:basic>
        </ns01:criteria>
        <ns01:columns xmlns:ns01="urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
          <ns01:basic>
            <ns02:amountRemaining xmlns:ns02="urn:common_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
            <ns02:internalId xmlns:ns02="urn:common_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
              <ns03:searchValue xmlns:ns03="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" internalId="null"/>
            </ns02:internalId>
          </ns01:basic>
        </ns01:columns>
      </ns0:searchRecord>
    </ns0:search></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
    
    DEBUG 2023-02-15 13:50:53,636 [[biz-prc-ent-finance-bulk-api].NetSuite_Config.04 SelectorRunner] [processor: netsuite-advance-search/processors/1/processors/0/processors/0; event: a91c2ba0-ad09-11ed-b6b5-88665a243a09] org.mule.service.http.impl.service.HttpMessageLogger.NetSuite_Config: REQUESTER
    0
    
    
    DEBUG 2023-02-15 13:50:58,153 [[finance-bulk-api].NetSuite_Config.04 SelectorRunner] [processor: netsuite-advance-search/processors/1/processors/0/processors/0; event: a91c2ba0-ad09-11ed-b6b5-88665a243a09] org.mule.service.http.impl.service.HttpMessageLogger.NetSuite_Config: REQUESTER
    HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out
    Server: AkamaiGHost
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 176
    Expires: Wed, 15 Feb 2023 08:20:58 GMT
    X-Reference-Error: 97.27697c68.1676449258.23382b2c
    Date: Wed, 15 Feb 2023 08:20:58 GMT
    Connection: close
    Akamai-GRN: 0.df523617.1676449254.1f240dc8
    
    <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
    An error occurred while processing your request.<p>
    Reference&#32;&#3

5;97&#46;27697c68&#46;1676449258&#46;23382b2c
</BODY></HTML>

    WARN  2023-02-15 13:50:58,155 [[MuleRuntime].uber.02: [finance-bulk-api].netsuite-to-salesforce-sync-shcedular-flow.BLOCKING @32c6a070] [processor: netsuite-advance-search/processors/1/processors/0/processors/0; event: a91c2ba0-ad09-11ed-b6b5-88665a243a09] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://client.internal.soap.mule.org/}ProxyService#{http://client.internal.soap.mule.org/}invoke has thrown exception, unwinding now
    java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:99) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the error is a timeout on the Netsuite infrastructure:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out
```

It it not possible to know the cause of the error from the data provided. It could be a Netsuite issue, a configuration issue (wrong connection address?), or simply that the operation takes too long to complete (data issue, which may vary between environments).

It would be recommended to upgrade to the [latest Mule Netsuite connector release](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/netsuite-connector-release-notes-mule-4) and test again. There have several fixes and improvements since the version you are using was released, including security fixes and error messages improvements. Even if it doesn't solve the issue you are experiencing you would be better covered against those issues.

Comment: Make sense @alad. I have tried updating the connector but getting the same error. But definitely there is something fishy from NetSuite side. I did not notice gateway time-out before. My bad. I will reach out to Netsuite team for further anallysis. Thanks a lot for time. Whatever answers I will get from netsuite team, will update here.

Comment: There was an outage in the netsuite at the time of error. It was only in the prod env which made to reach out here to seek help. This has been resolved. Thanks @aled for pointing out gateway time-out error